# Does macOS use different layout for shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, text-input

I'm a new Mac user, so please have mercy.

I have 2 keyboard layouts configured: Dvorak and US International.

My issue is the following: **when the Dvorak keyboard is selected, all shortcuts seem to use the US International layout.**

For example, to copy text, the shortcut is not <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but rather <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and the <kbd>J</kbd> on the Dvorak layout is in the location of the <kbd>C</kbd> on the  US International layout.

In other words, it seems like the layout for the shortcuts is using the US International layout, no matter which layout is active.

I can think of a few reasons for this, common shortcut locations (<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>) are clustered on the US International layout, but not on the Dvorak layout. Still, I'd like to use the layout I selected for all characters I type, regardless of the modifiers that happen to also be pressed at the same time.

How do I accomplish that? I cannot find any information about this here on the forum, nor in the Mac settings.

Comment: So, if I  understand you want the keys you use for the shortcut to follow the characters on each keyboard you select? That sounds good for muscle memory...

Comment: Apple provides 2 Dvoraks:  Dvorak and Dvorak Qwerty Command.  Have you tried both?

Comment: US International PC is a special layout which turns '"`~ into deadkeys to make accented characters for common European languages.  If you do not need that, I suggest you switch to US or ABC instead.

Comment: @TomGewecke thanks for that, i feel like such an idiot :) I hadn't seen the "normal" dvorak layout when setting up the system. If you want to write it up as an answer, go ahead and I'll accept it

Comment: Also @TomGewecke: I was aware of the dead keys in the US international layout, but I couldn't find the normal US layout. Turns out, in that case, US is written with periods: "U.S.", instead of without as in "US international". Thanks for making me double check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the input source called "Dvorak Qwerty ⌘."  Instead try the one called simply "Dvorak."